# How to resolve JSON Schema validation Error in Rest Assured - io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: Could not convert arguments

Tags: java, file, cucumber, rest-assured, json-schema-validator

I was trying to do the JSON schema validation in Rest Assured framework using the below code by reading the filename loginschema.json from src/test/resources/data folder and was getting CucumberException. Can someone provide their inputs on how to resolve this issue?

```
**UtilFile:**

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import io.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidator;

public void verifyResponseBody(File fileName)  {
String pathName = "src/test/resources/data/"+ fileName +".json";
response.then().assertThat().body(JsonSchemaValidator.matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath(pathName));
}

**Cucumber file:**
Then I see response matches file loginschema


**Common Stepdefintion File:**

@Then("I see response matches file {}")
public void i_see_response_matches_file(File fileName) {
    apiUtil.verifyResponseBody(fileName);
}    

**Error:**     
And I see response matches file loginschema                      # 
test.java.com.stepdefinitions.Common_StepDefintions.i_see_response_matches_file(java.io.File)
  io.cucumber.core.exception.CucumberException: Could not convert arguments for step [I see response matches file {}] defined at 'test.java.com.stepdefinitions.Common_StepDefintions.i_see_response_matches_file(java.io.File)'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get this error because you cannot just take an arbitrary sequence of chars from your steps (like you do with `{}`) and treat it as a `File` (argument type that your step takes).

You should change this `public void i_see_response_matches_file(File fileName)` to this `public void i_see_response_matches_file(String fileName)` and create `File` instance from that path internally within a step.

**P.S.** - Or you can create [custom parameter type](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-expressions#custom-parameter-types) and describer conversion there.

Answer (score 2):

Alexey already provided the reason for exception. Here I am showing you how to write custom parameter type for cucumber expression.

**Feature**:

```
Scenario Outline: File name
Then I see response matches file <loginschema>

Examples: 
  | loginschema                                                                |
  | C:\\Users\\Nandan\\EclipseWorkspace\\APIPractice\\PayLoads\\Response.json |
```

**StepDefinition**:

```
/*Converting the output parameter type to File*/

@ParameterType(".*")
public File file(String path) {
    return new File(path);
}

@Then("I see response matches file {file}")
public void i_see_response_matches_file(File fileName) {
    System.out.println(fileName);
}
```

**Output**:

```
C:\Users\Nandan\EclipseWorkspace\APIPractice\PayLoads\Response.json
```